# Angular2: ng2-bs3-modal not working for me

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular, ng2-bootstrap

```
Trying to build a simple Angular 2 app with modal dialogs using 'ng2-bs3-modal'
```

1. index.html

   ```html
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
     <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
     <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

     <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
     <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
     <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
     <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/bundles/ng2-bs3-modal.js"></script>

     <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
     <script>
       System.config({
         packages: {
           app: {
             format: 'register',
             defaultExtension: 'js'
           }
         }
       });
       System.import('app/main')
         .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
     </script>

   </head>

   <!-- 3. Display the application -->

   <body>
     <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

   </body>

   </html>
   ```
2. package.json

   ```
   {
     "name": "ng2-test",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "scripts": {
       "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",    
       "tsc": "tsc",
       "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
       "lite": "lite-server",
       "typings": "typings",
       "postinstall": "typings install" 
     },
     "license": "ISC",
     "dependencies": {
       "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",
       "systemjs": "0.19.27",
       "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
       "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
       "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
       "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
       "zone.js": "0.6.12"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
       "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
       "typescript": "^1.8.10",
       "typings":"^1.0.4"
     }
   }
   ```
3. tsconfig.json

   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "module": "system",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       "experimentalDecorators": true,
       "removeComments": false,
       "noImplicitAny": false
     },
     "exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "typings/main",
       "typings/main.d.ts"
     ]
   }
4. typings.json

   {
     "ambientDependencies": {
       "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#6697d6f7dadbf5773cb40ecda35a76027e0783b2"
     }
   }
5. app/main.ts

   import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser' // import bootstrap
   import {AppComponent} from './app.component' // import the component we just created
   import {AComponent} from './a.component' // 
   //import {UserLoginModalComponent} from './user-login.component' //

   bootstrap(AppComponent); // finally bootstrap it.
   bootstrap(AComponent);
   //bootstrap(UserLoginModalComponent);
6. app/app.component.ts

   ```
   import {Component} from 'angular2/core'; // <-- importing Component from core
   //import {AComponent} from './a.component';

   @Component({
       selector: 'my-app', //<----the element defined in the index.html
       template: '<h1>Angular2, Hello {{name}}</h1><br>' // <---this is the template to put in the component.
     //  directives: [AComponent],
   })
   export class AppComponent { 
       name: string;
       constructor(){
           this.name = "ANIL";
       }
   } // <--- we need to export the class AppComponent.
   ```
7. app/a.component.ts

   ```
   import {Component} from 'angular2/core'; // <-- importing Component from core
   //import {AComponent} from './a.component';

   @Component({
       selector: 'my-app', //<----the element defined in the index.html
       template: '<h1>Angular2, Hello {{name}}</h1><br>' // <---this is the template to put in the component.
     //  directives: [AComponent],
   })
   export class AppComponent { 
       name: string;
       constructor(){
           this.name = "ANIL";
       }
   } // <--- we need to export the class AppComponent.
   ```
8. app/user-login.component.ts

   ```
   import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
   import {MODAL_DIRECTIVES, ModalComponent} from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';

   @Component({
       selector: 'user-login-modal',
       directives: [MODAL_DIRECTIVES],
       template: `
           <modal #modal [keyboard]="false" [backdrop]="'static'">
               <modal-header [show-close]="false">
                   <h4 class="modal-title">I am a modal!</h4>
               </modal-header>
               <modal-body>
                   Hello World!
               </modal-body>
               <modal-footer [show-default-buttons]="true"></modal-footer>
           </modal>
       `
   })
   export class UserLoginModalComponent {

       @ViewChild(ModalComponent)
       modal: ModalComponent;

       open(){
           this.modal.open();
       }

       close(){
           this.modal.close();
       }
   }
   ```

I see ng2-bs3-modal module is still trying to access @angular/core, i think it should point to angular2/core?
I also tried adding 'map' in system config js, but it was not taking the '.js' extension while accessing the @angular/core(even though   defaultExtension: 'js' was present in system config js).

Please help!!!

Below is console log trace,

angular2-polyfills.js:127 GET http://localhost:3000/@angular/core 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:127ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:362Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:299(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:148send @ VM1684:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1156(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1739ZoneAwarePromise @ angular2-polyfills.js:610(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1738(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2764(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3338(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3605(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3990(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4453(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4705(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:408ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:349Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:242(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:597ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:382Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:282drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:500ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:452
angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/core(…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very silly of me, missed to include the bootstrap CSS

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css

and add ng2-bs3-modal latest version(it looks for @angular/ packages not angular/

```
"ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.6.1"
```

used mapping for angular rc version in system config js as below

```
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',

    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
```

and

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.6.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.10",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0"
  },
```